# Anyway to Check if any datatable.Columns is added vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset with a datatable with Columns.

I fill dataset with this code in Winforms

```
    myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from users", strSqlConn)
    myAdapter.Fill(dsDataset, "Users")
    dcPk(0) = dsDataset.Tables("Users").Columns("FirstName")
    dcPk(1) = dsDataset.Tables("Users").Columns("LastName")
    dsDataset.Tables("Users").PrimaryKey = dcPk
```

Is it anyway to check if any datatable.Columns is added vb.net? Later in code For example "amount" is added

```
dsDataset.Tables("Users").Columns.Add("amount", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
```

What I really want - I have alot of datasets and I want to see if it any real changes in them (not added columns whois not part of the database) if not, dont save to database.

When I use GetChanges it says I have changes if I have added columns, but the  added columns should be excluded.

Now I have hardcoded the added columns to exclude them in the check, it works but thats not a good way to maintain. Another way is to make a copy of all datasets and compare them, in the copy there is no added columns. But Im not sure about performance when its alot of datasets...

Like in rows

```
  If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
        'Do something
  end if
```

Comment: You mean you want to see if a column with a certain column name exists? Or if the `DataTable` has any columns added?

Comment: I want to see if the DataTable has any columns added

Comment: Why not just run an `If statement`? Eg; `If DataTable.Columns.Count > 0 Then`?

Comment: I have Edited my question, to make i more clear what I want. I to find that column "amount" is added for example

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [GetChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the DataTable object, like so...

```
dim t as DataTable = MyDataTable.GetChanges()
If t IsNot Nothing then
' There were changes to the table
Else
' There were no changes to the table
End If
```

Please be sure to read the documentation page that I linked to be sure that it meets your requirements.

Comment: I have read the link GetChanges() but I cant find anyway to use it to find added columns. Have you any hint?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  Why do you need to detect a new column?  What happens in your application that requires you to do this?  Adding columns to tables isn't something that I would expect to happen very often.

Comment: The codebase is big and its more than 1 developer, if someone in the future is adding a new column not part of the database and dont  exclude the column in the check , the application think its changes in.

I want if its possible to avoid bugs in the future if someone miss to exclude new columns

It works with exclude the columns in the code, but its not a good way I think!.

Comment: Ah.  You don't have an application problem; you have a source code control problem.  Are you using a source code control system?  (Accurev, Git, Subversion, etc.)

Comment: This is quickly approaching something that's beyond StackOverflow, but your build process should probably include a step where the database from the current build is compared to the database from the previous build, and a script is generated that implements the changes.